# How to set xlabel values in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I want to plot a histogram of electrical resistivity values ranging from 0 to 1200, spaced out around 200 units between. I have my values saved in a file on my laptop; there are 1600 measurements each of which can be any number in that range. However, when I try to create a histogram from that list of values, the x-axis labels takes on every value in that list [How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeIf6.png), rather than 0 - 200 - 400 - 600 - 800 - 1000 - 1200, as I want. [How I would like it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn0Xu.png) . In short, how do I change the xlabel to go from 1600 individual values to 0 - 200 - 400 - 600 - 800 - 1000 - 1200?

I hope you can see the images - I'm not allowed to post them directly. If not, I hope that my explanation was relatively clear. Thanks!

Thanks so far but plt.xticks(ticks=[0, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000, 1200]) doesn't quite work: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAYqj.png)

Comment: Usually you can control the axis ticks with `ax.set_xticks([0,200,400,600])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should set `xticks` as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xticks(ticks=[0, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000])
```

Comment: Your solution worked! My issue is that the values in the list were not integers but strings. I would give you a like but I don't have enough reputation points - but thanks a lot.

Comment: You can set labels as well using `plt.xticks(ticks=[1, 2, 3], labels=['a', 'b', 'c'])`

Comment: in this case in place of 1, 2, and 3 in the figure it will be a, b, and c. If your x and y values are string you can do a simpler thing. Just use `plt.xticks(ticks=x[::10])` then it will put 1 in every then of x on the axis. I hope it helps.